# Why do I keep getting a syntax error? What's the solution for this?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

```
/**
 * This function creates an ExtendScript script that creates a new project in Adobe Premiere Pro.
 * 
 * @returns {string} The ExtendScript code to create a new project
 */
function createPremiereProProject() {
  try {
    // Define the ExtendScript code to create a new project
    const extendScriptCode = `
      var newProject = app.newProject();
    `;
    
    // Return the ExtendScript code
    return extendScriptCode;
  } catch (err) {
    // Log the error
    console.error(err);
    
    // Return an empty string
    return '';
  }
}
```

```js
const extendScriptCode = `
      var newProject = app.newProject();`;
```

Does this have a syntax error?

I tried it multiple times and it keeps giving me this error. It's a command which creates a new project in Premiere Pro.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem from your code. Are you using an `eval()` somewhere else?

Comment: Where are you running that script? What is the exact syntax error?

Comment: The code doesn't look like a proper Extendsript. It looks like a modern Javascript (Node.js may be). I doubt the code will run within Adobe apps at all. For example in Extendscript it would be `$.writeln(err)` instead of `console.error(err)` and it doesn't handle the back quote symbols `\``, you have to use straight single quotes `'''` instead. Etc.

Comment: Try to remove all the lines an use just one of them: `var newProject = app.newProject();`